# How to Add HTTP Request Defaults to .jmx using Java Code

Tags: java, jmeter

Jmeter Developer. I have already composed a .jmx using Java code by calling Jmeter's backend API.  Now, I need to add Request Defaults Componet into my .jmx. However, I can not find the right API call on Java doc of Jmeter.

Where is the HTTP Request Defaults being defined in Java Doc and How can I add them?

```
newSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
```

Something like above that create a http request sampler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant class is [ConfigTestElement](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/ConfigTestElement.html) which can be initialized as follows:

```
ConfigTestElement httpRequestDefaults = new ConfigTestElement();
httpRequestDefaults.setName("HTTP Request Defaults");
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty(new TestElementProperty("HTTPsampler.Arguments", new HTTPArgumentsPanel().createTestElement()));
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty("HTTPSampler.domain", "hostname or IP address of your server");
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty("HTTPSampler.port", "1234");
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty("HTTPSampler.protocol", "https");
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty("HTTPSampler.contentEncoding", "UTF-8");
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty("HTTPSampler.path", "/");
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty("HTTPSampler.concurrentPool", "6");
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty("HTTPSampler.connect_timeout", "10000");
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty("HTTPSampler.response_timeout", "10000");
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ConfigTestElement.class.getName());
httpRequestDefaults.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpDefaultsGui.class.getName());
```

Replace the properties with the values of your choice including eventual default parameters.

References:

- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui/)
- [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/)

Answer (score 0):

**You can find its hierarchy as follow:**

```
Class HttpDefaultsGui
 java.lang.Object
  java.awt.Component
   java.awt.Container
    javax.swing.JComponent
     javax.swing.JPanel
      org.apache.jmeter.gui.AbstractJMeterGuiComponent
       org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.AbstractConfigGui
        org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.config.gui.HttpDefaultsGui
```

> **Note:** Please visit the link to find more information. It was tricky to find
>   it thou.  [HttpDefaultsGui_Class][1]
>
> [1]:
>   https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/config/gui/HttpDefaultsGui.html

Comment: Hey @Nawar thanks for the answer, I edit a little bit of my question, would you able to answer the edit question as well?

Comment: Hi Alex, my experience is very little in Java. If I understood your question, I think  Http Request Defaults is defined in (HttpDefaultsGui) class. So you should be able to use it like any Java class by importing it, then create an object and used the the imported class methods to do what you want. If you can share more details, code and screen shots maybe more people understand the problem and help. Thanks

Comment: ok, thanks you. Once I figure out, I'll post my solution here